# Help identifying and getting started with this Fibre Channel equipment

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, hp, fibre-channel

Some old(?) fiber channel equipment is being donated to my company and I need help identifying what exactly I have, and how to get it up and running if possible.

I have two HP rack units, each with 14 vertically oriented fiber channel drives, 146GB each drive.

On the outside of the enclosure is AD524B.   I found reference that this may be known as an HP EVA 8000?     Looks similar to [this](http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/610101-HP.jpg), but with fibre channel drives.    [This picture](http://www.bujarra.com/imagenes3/EVA%20Disk%20Drive%20Enclosure%20BACK.jpg) shows what the back looks like, with the EMU and IO modules A&B.

I also have a Cisco Fibre switch c9020-20k9.

Finally for a server, I have an HP Proliant DL380 G4 (no fibre card that I can see).

I would imagine at a minimum I need some fiber cables (copper type I think) to from the IO modules.

Can you help me more specifically identify this and at least point me at where to find information / documentation on how to get this going (even if only as a directly connected 'drive')?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's an EVA8000 with a couple of FC shelves, you'll need the interconnecting cables between the controllers and shelves, an FC HBA for your 380 and the cables between those too. You'll also need a copy of HP's Command View EVA and the licence to use the disk capacity you have. After that it's pretty straightforward, if you know about FC anyway, you could do with updating all of the various firmware revisions (controllers, disks & switch) but physically connecting them together is the easy bit, configuring the switch is notoriously tricky. If you're only going to connect the EVA to one server you don't actually need the switch at all, just put the EVA into 'FCAL' mode rather than 'fabric' mode. What OS is on the 380 and does it support MPIO? [HERE](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DocumentIndex.jsp?contentType=SupportManual&lang=en&cc=uk&docIndexId=64902&taskId=101&prodTypeId=12169&prodSeriesId=470490) is the root of the documentation anyway. Sorry for the stream of consciousness, just got off a plane.

Comment: Thank you.   If I were to use a FC HBA in the server, is there any alternative to using the HP software?